# Store array value in Database frontend angular2 backend php?

Tags: php, angular

Hello first of all sorry if this question already ask?
But I am stuck in this what exactly I want to is. I am trying to create a rest api for my angular2 frontend. All works fine as I called rest api and from angular2 and start database value in particular table. like

```html
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `create_profile`(`developerType`, `skills`, `level`, `workType`, `message`) VALUES (:developerType, :skills, :level, :workType, :message)");$stmt->bindParam(':developerType', $params->developerType);
```

But I am stuck how to store a value which contains array at the place of value like in my skills table there is an array with 2 values but how can I store it into database.

I am using like this ..

```html
$stmt->bindParam(':skills', $data);
```

but its not working I know I missed something but what that I don't know. please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try

```html
$data = array();
$skillSet = $params->skills;
foreach($skillSet as $team)
    $data[] = "" . addslashes($team->skillName) . "";

$data = implode("," , $data);

$stmt->bindParam(':skills', $data);
```

you have to implode your array first and after that it can be store in the database hope it will help you.:)

Comment: Thank you buddy your code save my life and its working thanks alot